# Braintree liabilityShifted is false and status is lookup_error

Tags: production, braintree

I followed Braintree tutorial to upgrade to 3DS2: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/migration/javascript/v3
Everything works fine for sandbox, but after swithing to production, lookup request (url something like https://api.braintreegateway.com/merchants//client_api/v1/payment_methods//three_d_secure/lookup) fails with following result inside response:

```
threeDSecureInfo: {
status: "lookup_error",
liabilityShiftPossible: false,
liabilityShifted: false
...
}
```

This lookup response is returned after hosted fields should be tokenized and bank verification should take place with custom UI to verify card.
With 3DS1 we ditn't have any problems and cards were verified.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: If your imlementation is working without problems for Sandbox, Contact support. It was an issue on Braintree side in my case.

Comment: I have a feeling you are right, I did contact them although they took 11 days just to respond.
What a bunch of amateurs. I am waiting for the contract with a different payment processor, then I will gladly ditch Braintree. They are expensive and their software is just crap.

Answer (score 1):

3DS is enabled in sandbox automatically to merchants but will have to contact BT to enable in production. There's usually going to be a cost involved per transaction.

> In sandbox, 3D Secure is automatically enabled for all merchants.
>
> In production, 3D Secure is not automatically enabled in production
> accounts and is only compatible with certain Braintree configurations
> in specific regions. Contact us if you're interested in 3D Secure.

https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/configuration

Comment: They say that in docs, but when we contacted them they said there was no cost. did take about a week to turn on.  Also 3DS2 isn't available to merchants in our area yet with braintree.